# How can I leave Superhot when playing on my Oculus Quest?

Tags: superhot-vr

I've been playing Superhot on my Oculus Quest. I have been unable to exit the game. Either leaving the game or switching to the main process to kill it would be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying about every single combination of buttons on the controllers, I have found that tapping the Oculus button (which when pressed longer resets your location) pauses the game and brings up a menu that allows you to quit.